# Multiple searches with FOSElasticaBundle for a keyword

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

How to search with original keyword and transformed keyword?
I have indexed data like this with Elastica:

```
id1: {
    content: "Phòng tránh rủi ro",
    content_canonical: "Phong tranh rui ro"
},
id2: {
    content: "Phóng nhanh vượt ẩu",
    content_canonical: "Phong nhanh vuot au"
},
id3: {
    content: "Mô phỏng thực tế",
    content_canonical: "Mo phong thuc te"
}
```

Now, when people want to search for keyword `phòng`, I want to search for keyword `phong` (transformed from `phòng`) as well but the former should be scored higher than the latter.

How to do it with FOSElasticaBundle or with ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution:

```
                analysis:
                    analyzer:
                        post_analyzer:
                            tokenizer: lowercase
                            filter: [ standard, my_ascii_folding ]
                    filter:
                        my_ascii_folding:
                            type: asciifolding
                            preserve_original: true
```

Then `post_analyzer` need to be applied to the fields `content`. And `content_canonical` is not needed as `asciifolding` will do it automatically.